# How do you center an image float? Also its text at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I already centered the images inside the "main-content" class, but I don't know if I do it right. And the second thing that I want to do is to center also the text, but if I use margin it also affects the images. Sorry for my confusing code, I'm just only a beginner.

Here is the HTML5 markup:

```
<main class="main-content">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="Products/groceries-pets/Fruits-Package.html">
              <img
                src="./Images/Products/groceries-pets/fruits-package.jpg"
                class="img-content"
              />
            </a>
            <br />
            <div>
              <p href="Products/groceries-pets/Fruits-Package.html" class="desc">
                <strong>Fruit Package</strong> <em> P1200 </em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="item">
            <a href="products/home-living/Indoor-Plant.html">
              <img
                src="./Images/products/home-living/indoor-plant.jpg"
                class="img-content"
              />
            </a>
            <br />
            <div>
              <p href="products/home-living/Indoor-Plant.html" class="desc">
                <strong> Indoor Plant </strong> <em> P300 </em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="item">
            <a href="Products/babies-toys/Baby-Cars.html">
              <img
                src="./Images/Products/babies-toys/baby-cars.jpg"
                class="img-content"
              />
            </a>
            <br />
            <div>
              <p href="Products/babies-toys/Baby-Cars.html" class="desc">
                <strong> Baby Cars</strong> <em> P150 </em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="item">
            <a href="Products/fashion/Black-Shirt.html">
              <img
                src="./Images/Products/fashion/black-shirt.jpg"
                class="img-content"
              />
            </a>
            <br />
            <div>
              <p href="Products/fashion/Black-Shirt.html" class="desc">
                <strong> Black Shirt</strong> <em> P400 </em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.main-content {
  background-color: rgb(219, 95, 95);
  height: 340px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 140px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  float: left;
}

.img-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px -200px 0px 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.desc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to center all the images?

Comment: Yes, with the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `margin` from `.img-content` so that it aligns to the text, then add a `margin` to `.item` instead:

```css
.main-content {
  background-color: rgb(219, 95, 95);
  height: 340px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 140px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.img-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: green;
}

.desc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="Products/groceries-pets/Fruits-Package.html">
      <img src="./Images/Products/groceries-pets/fruits-package.jpg" class="img-content" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <div>
      <p href="Products/groceries-pets/Fruits-Package.html" class="desc">
        <strong>Fruit Package</strong> <em> P1200 </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="products/home-living/Indoor-Plant.html">
      <img src="./Images/products/home-living/indoor-plant.jpg" class="img-content" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <div>
      <p href="products/home-living/Indoor-Plant.html" class="desc">
        <strong> Indoor Plant </strong> <em> P300 </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="Products/babies-toys/Baby-Cars.html">
      <img src="./Images/Products/babies-toys/baby-cars.jpg" class="img-content" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <div>
      <p href="Products/babies-toys/Baby-Cars.html" class="desc">
        <strong> Baby Cars</strong> <em> P150 </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="Products/fashion/Black-Shirt.html">
      <img src="./Images/Products/fashion/black-shirt.jpg" class="img-content" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <div>
      <p href="Products/fashion/Black-Shirt.html" class="desc">
        <strong> Black Shirt</strong> <em> P400 </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the Css properties is the `display` property.

This property will put the items you have horizontally.

If you want to place it vertically,
Add this property after `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`.

Then use the properties `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`
This property will center the item.